# SQL Replace multiple variables from another table in query result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a team schedule table that looks like this:

DBO.SCHEDULE

```
Game1_Time  |  Game1_Home_Team   | Game1_Away_Team 
===================================================
12:00:00    |         1          |         2
```

I want to replace the team values with their corresponding team that exists in another table:

DBO.TEAM

```
Team_Number  |  Team_Name
========================
    1        |  The Monsters
    2        |  Bug Bites
```

TRYING TO DO THIS:
How do I replace the 1 & 2 in Schedule with "The Monsters" & "Bug Bites" in a query result?

```
Game1_Time  |  Home Team         | Away Team 
===================================================
12:00:00    |  The Monsters      |  Bug Bites
```

Comment: [JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)

Comment: I'm having a hard time joining on two values in one row.

Comment: you can join tables multiple times using aliases.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

basically just do two joins one for the home name and one for the away name.

```
SELECT 
     s.Game1_Time, 
     t.Team_Name as 'Home Team', 
     t1.Team_Name as 'Away Team'
FROM `SCHEDULE` s
JOIN `TEAM` t on t.Team_Number = s.Game1_Home_Team
JOIN `TEAM` t1 on t1.Team_Number = s.Game1_Away_Team
```

i added backticks because schedule is a keyword so just to not mess anything up you should use backtics on the tablename

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/78670/1)