# How to replace id's with values from another table

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT st.part_location_id_from, st.part_location_id_to, st.loginid
FROM stock_transfer AS st, stock_transfer_confirmation AS stc
WHERE st.id = stc.stock_transfer_id
AND stc.confirmed = 0;
```

It retrieves all unconfirmed stock transfers. I would like to replace the id from `part_stock_location_id_from` and `part_stock_location_id_to` with the name of the location which I have in another table like:

```
    id descr
    1  Warehouse A
    2  Warehouse B
    2  Store A
```

etc.

is there a way to get this in one query?

Comment: Yes, make an inner select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer of sagi did not really work correctly.

I've found a much simpler and working solution in another thread:

[SQL Replace multiple variables from another table in query result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25365327/sql-replace-multiple-variables-from-another-table-in-query-result/25365494#25365494)