# How to update field values with values from another table

Tags: mysql

I have four tables by the name candidate, program_type, program_of_interest and desired_intake. The table candidate has a many to one relationship with the rest of the three tables.

The candidate table looks like this:
[image]

The program_type table:
[image]

The program_of_interest table:
[image]

The desired_intake table:
[image]

I am trying to replace the program_type,program_of_interest,desired_intake id's in the candidate table with the corresponding values in their respective tables.
I am able to select the values as needed with help from this thread [SQL Replace multiple variables from another table in query result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25365327/sql-replace-multiple-variables-from-another-table-in-query-result/25365494#25365494). Here is my solution to select:

```
SELECT 
     c.id, 
     p.value as 'Program type', 
     p1.value as 'Program of interest',
     d.value as 'Desired intake'
FROM candidate c
JOIN program_type p on p.id = c.program_type
JOIN program_of_interest p1 on p1.id = c.program_of_interest
JOIN desired_intake d on d.id = c.desired_intake
```

My question is how do I replace the ids in the candidate table with their respective values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an update basend on join  as

```
  Update candidate c
  INNER JOIN program_type p on p.id = c.program_type
  INNER JOIN program_of_interest p1 on p1.id = c.program_of_interest
  INNER JOIN desired_intake d on d.id = c.desired_intake
    set c.program_type = p.value,
        c.program_of_interest = p1.value,
        c.desired_intake  = d.value
```

but seems strange you want update eg: program_type with the value (c.program_type = p.value) 
and you are using program_type for join   ( p.id = c.program_type)

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick response. However the query returns false

Comment: here is the error `MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'JOIN program_type p on p.id = c.program_type
  JOIN program_of_interest p1 on p' at line 5`

Comment: I tried the updated query but gives error `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'intake = d.value' at line 7`

Comment: Itried again, new error `#1054 - Unknown column 'c.program_type' in 'field list'`

Comment: Tried the new answer, getting new error `#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`migrationproject`.`candidate`, CONSTRAINT `FK_C8B28E441CBFA1E4` FOREIGN KEY (`program_of_interest`) REFERENCES `program_of_interest` (`id`))`

Comment: You can't change the foreign key ..  the you can't update the values  you need .. (you should remove the constrains ... perform the update and then reassign the constrains