# Linking one column in a table to two columns in another table

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

My game and team schedule is as follows

**DBO.GAME**

```
GameTime  |    HomeTeamID      |    AwayTeamID
===================================================
12:00     |         1          |         2
```

I want to replace the team values with their corresponding team that exists in another table:

**DBO.TEAM**

```
  TeamID     |  TeamName
========================
    1        |  AC Milan
    2        |  Paris
```

I am using an Access form, I am using a combobox to select the date, and onupdate the list box with the below is filled out fine.
I am able to achieve this:

```
GameTime    |  HomeTeamID  |   AwayTeamID 
===========================================
12:00       |       1      |      2
```

**I am trying to display the TEAM NAME instead of the TeamID**

```
GameTime    |  Home Team   |   Away Team
===========================================
12:00       |   AC Milan   |     Paris
```

Below is the query I am trying to use.

```
SELECT g.GameTime, t.TeamName as 'Home Team' , t.TeamName as 'Away Team'
FROM GAME AS g 
INNER JOIN TEAM AS t ON g.HomeTeamID = t.TeamID 
INNER JOIN TEAM AS t ON g.AwayTeamID = t.TeamID
```

I receive the error:

```
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression
```

I've used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25365327/sql-replace-multiple-variables-from-another-table-in-query-result/25365494#25365494) solution as a fix, but it doesn't seem to work.

[My Access Game/Team relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKD8b.jpg)

Comment: MS Access has some weird syntax for multiple joins...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854969/sql-multiple-join-statement

Comment: @jarth why you didnt close it as duplicated?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, done!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
g.GameTime, 
t1.TeamName as 'Home Team',
t2.TeamName as 'Away Team'
FROM 
GAME g 
INNER JOIN TEAM AS t1 ON g.HomeTeamID = t1.TeamID 
INNER JOIN TEAM AS t2 ON g.AwayTeamID = t2.TeamID;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854969/sql-multiple-join-statement